# mysql in select big data slowdown

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$sql = "SELECT CC.*, CS.name as status_name, OS.name AS order_status_name, OS.id as order_status_id, O.payment_way, O.ship_country,O.bank_id,O.payment_text, O.reference_no, O.date_comp, O.rate as rate, O.currency as currency, IF(O.payment_way=4,'TEST',B.name) as bank_name, ICR.cancel_id, ICR.result, ICR.response 
FROM cancels CC 
INNER JOIN orders O ON O.id = CC.order_id 
LEFT JOIN order_products OP ON OP.parent=O.id 
LEFT JOIN product_variants PV ON PV.id=OP.product_variant_id 
LEFT JOIN products P ON P.id=PV.product_id 
LEFT JOIN banks B ON B.id=O.bank_id 
LEFT JOIN order_status OS ON OS.id = O.status 
LEFT JOIN mp_external_order AS meo ON meo.mdns_order_id = O.id 
LEFT JOIN cancel_status AS CS ON CS.cname = CC.status 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT IC.cancel_id, IC.result, IC.response, MAX(IC.id) AS cancels FROM internal_cancel_requests IC GROUP BY IC.cancel_id, IC.result, IC.response) AS ICR ON CC.id = ICR.cancel_id 
WHERE CC.date_add BETWEEN '2021-03-10 00:00:00' AND '2021-08-10 23:59:59' AND CC.deleted = 0 AND CC.total <> 0 AND meo.id IS NULL AND CC.status NOT IN ('REF', 'M_REF') GROUP BY CC.id ORDER BY C.date_add ASC";

$query = selectQuery($sql);
```

in the code block above

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT IC.cancel_id, IC.result, IC.response, MAX(IC.id) AS cancels FROM internal_cancel_requests IC GROUP BY IC.cancel_id, IC.result, IC.response) AS ICR ON CC.id = ICR.cancel_id
```

line causing slownes.

Without changing the date range and adding limits for uploaded big data. How should I change this line of code to improve performance.

internal_cancel_requests table

| id | cancel_id | response | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1250 | xxxxx | 1 |
| 2 | 1250 | xyxyxy | 0 |
| 3 | 1251 | xx | 0 |

in the above table For record number 1250 cancel_id, record number 2 must be brought

Comment: Are all the needed indexes define?

Comment: yes indexes defined.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN (SELECT IC.cancel_id, IC.result, IC.response, MAX(IC.id) AS cancels FROM internal_cancel_requests IC GROUP BY IC.cancel_id, IC.result, IC.response) AS ICR ON CC.id = ICR.cancel_id` I can only make changes to this line or change the way it is used.

Comment: From that join I assume it is the sub-select that causes the slowness, and from that probably the `GROUP BY` bit. For a big dataset that requires quite a bit of processing.

Comment: If I don't use group by, bad data will be listed.

Comment: There are always other ways to reach a goal. You could simplify it to `(SELECT DISTINCT cancel_id FROM internal_cancel_requests) AS ICR` and only when you actually need the grouped data you create it. We can't tell what your query is doing, so it is difficult to be helpful.

Comment: The query needs to go according to the id value of the canceled transaction and fetch the values ​​of the last log record related to that transaction.

Comment: To understand your whole query I would need much more information. The point I was trying to make is that the sub-query is slow because you `GROUP BY` a whole table. That would take a long time if that table is big. Better find another way to retrieve the data. I think you would ever only need a tiny bit of that data anyway.